# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - I have added the script in the bottom of the body property

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mapping

This is a project for twin city. The project is working absolutely fine in my own server - localhost. But it is not working when I try in ionos server. if you go on my website sharminrony.co.uk and follow the link for project twin city then you will be able to see the error yourself. It's just not working in ionos server but it works in localhost.
Any idea what is wrong with it??

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
//do work

var slideIndex = 1;

window.onload = function() {
    showDivs(slideIndex);**strong text**
};

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) 
  {
    slideIndex = 1
  }    

  if (n < 1) 
  {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
  {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";    //throwing error in this line
}

function openWeather(evt, day) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, display;
  
  window.location.href='#weatherHours';

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  display = document.getElementsByClassName(day);

  for (var i=0; i < display.length; i+=1)
  {
    display[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
  
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
});
```

[image]

Comment: Well simply there isn't any element with mySlides as class name

Comment: How is it possible that it works fine in localhost

Comment: I don't know I don't have all your code

Answer (score 0):

can u try adding a check for if x[slideIndex-1] is present at that moment? i think that will solve your problem.

```
if (x[slideIndex-1]) { x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";}
```

Comment: it did solve the problem but my map is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with `mySlides` as class name.

And you have an error in `mapping.js` as you can see

Change your function like this

```js
function initialize(woeid) {
  var cityArray = []; // You have to put your variable here
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/getMapping.php",
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(overallArray) {
      for (var i = 0; i < overallArray.length; i++) {
        if (overallArray[i].woeid == woeid) {
          cityArray = overallArray[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      var cityHashTags = cityArray.hashTags.split(";");

      document.getElementById("cityTitle").innerHTML = cityArray.name;
      document.getElementById("rssLink").href = "php/getRssFeed.php?woeid=" + cityArray.woeid;
      document.getElementById("cityDescription").innerHTML = cityArray.desc;
      document.getElementById("cityPopulation").innerHTML = `Population: ${cityArray.curPop}`;
      document.getElementById("cityCountry").innerHTML = `Country: ${cityArray.country}`;
      document.getElementById("cityLat").innerHTML = `Lat : ${cityArray.lat}`;
      document.getElementById("cityLong").innerHTML = `Long : ${cityArray.lng}`;

      for (var j = 0; j < cityHashTags.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("cityTwitter").innerHTML += "<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=" + cityHashTags[j] + "' target='_blank'>#" + cityHashTags[j] + "</a>&nbsp&nbsp";
      }

      if (0 < cityArray.images.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cityArray.images.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById("cityPhotos").innerHTML += '<div class="w3-display-container mySlides w3-animate-opacity"><img src="pictures/poi/' + cityArray.images[i].imageFle + '" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><h4>' + cityArray.images[i].name + '</h4><p style="text-align:center;">' + cityArray.images[i].desc + '</p></div>';
        }
      }

      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(cityArray.lat, cityArray.lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: 1
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      setMarkers(map, cityArray.poi);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I added the variable but no luck. the project works completely fine from localhost. I shared it with ionos using filezilla. So i can't mis-match the script. is there anything else i could try without changing the code

Comment: You have an error: "<br><h1>Error : Can't Connect To Database</h1><br>Connection failed: No such file or directory" check the connection to your database

Comment: http://sharminrony.co.uk/projects/twin_city/publicHTML/php/getMapping.php?_=1618844093488

Comment: I was trying to upload the files again in the server. Thats why it's showing this error. it should work now